# Pyspark dataframe divide column by constant value in the column, without collecting dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe of user login sessions count on a website, for each specific day but segmented by registration day. I want to divide those counts by the counts on the day of registration to get fractional values. This means that where the field daysSinceRegistration is 0, the fractional value will always be 1.

```
+----------+----------+---------------------+-----+
|sessionDay|   regDate|daysSinceRegistration|count|
+----------+----------+---------------------+-----+
|2019-06-11|2019-06-10|                    1| 6463|
|2019-06-11|2019-06-11|                    0|14452|
|2019-06-11|2019-06-09|                    2| 3878|
+----------+----------+---------------------+-----+
```

I know this can be done as follows:

```
dayZeroCount = sessions_no_segmentations.filter(sessions_no_segmentations['daysSinceRegistration'] == 0).collect()[0]['count']
    sessions_no_segmentations = sessions_no_segmentations.withColumn('percentUsers', fun.col('count')/dayZeroCount)
```

However, this requires a `collect()` call which is quite heavy, and this code needs to be run a lot of times (about 300 different dataframes) on a short time. Calling `collect()` does not seem like the ideal approach.

Are there ways I can have my desired result without calling this `collect()` call?

Comment: A dataframe has only one row with `daysSinceRegistration == 0`?

Comment: Just join the dataframe to itself on that condition. Something like `df.alias("r").join(df.where("daysSinceRegistration == 0").select("count").alias("r")).selectExpr("r.*, r.count / l.count as percentUsers")`

Comment: Needed to do some tinkering still, but it indeed did the trick! Thank you so much!